# When $X_t$ is conditionally normal distributed and has density $p_t$, how can we compute $\text E\left[\left\|\nabla\ln p_t(X_t)\right\|^2\right]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $\mathbb R^d$-valued process. Assume $$\operatorname P\left[X_t\in\;\cdot\;\mid X_0\right]=\mathcal N(X_0,\Sigma_t)\tag1$$ for some covariance matrix $\Sigma_t$. Moreover, assume $X_t$ has density $p_t$ with respect to the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Let $\varphi_{\Sigma_t}$ denote the density of the $d$-dimensional normal distribution with mean $0$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma_t$. By assumption, $$p_t=p_0\ast\varphi_{\Sigma_t}\tag2$$ (is the convolution of $p_0$ and $\varphi_{\Sigma_t}$). Now, what I need to do is *numerically* compute/estimate $$\operatorname E\left[\left\|\nabla\ln p_t(X_t)\right\|^2\right]\tag3.$$

Please assume that we do not know the distribution of $X_0$. Instead, we only have i.i.d. samples drawn from the distribution of $X_0$. And given such a sample, I'm able to produce a sample from $X_t$ which is distributed according to $(1)$.

I'm not sure what exactly I need to do. Maybe it's worth noting that $$\nabla\ln p_t=\frac{p_0\ast\nabla\varphi_{\Sigma_t}}{p_0\ast\varphi_{\Sigma_t}}\tag4,$$ but since I don't see that this simplifies further, I'm stuck with that.

*Remark*: For the numerical computation, please note that I do *not* actually know $\Sigma_t$. I only know that it exists. So, what I'm doing, is computing $\Sigma_t$ numerically as well.